# RewriteRule (Reverse Proxy) of front page in htaccess not working

Tags: reverse-proxy, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

The following rule should target my front page (WordPress) to serve a different page instead.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^($|\/$|\?|\/\?)
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yy.example.com [P]
```

so `https://example.com` should serve `https://yy.example.com` behind the scenes.

I also do this with several other sub-sites, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/zzz($|\/$|\?|\/\?)
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yy.example.com/zzz [P]
```

which successfully serves `https://yy.example.com/zzz` for a request on `https://example.com/zzz`. This needs to be done for specific URLs only, and not for the whole domain btw.

However, the first rule for the front page does not work.

If I use `[L,R=301]` instead, it does redirect to `https://yy.example.com` so the `RewriteCond` work correctly. But for some reason, only on the front page, the `RewriteRule` does not work with `[P]` while it does work with `[L,R]`.

What could be the reason? Is there anything specific that needs to be added for the front page? Is WordPress somehow messing with this? The rewrite rules are at the very top of the `.htaccess` file, so no earlier rule is messing with this. Also note that `[R]` works which also indicates that this rule is actually reached but not correctly executed when using `[P]` directive.

**UPDATE:**
The following rule (by MrWhite) makes is possible to correctly redirect the front page:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://yy.example.com/ [P]
```

BUT, since there is Wordpress running, it also redirects any other Wordpress page, because from what I see, Wordpress rewrites any "non-existing" path (due to pretty links, like https://example.com/zzz) to index.php, which then handles which page to display, with this default Wordpress directives.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

So, we are getting close, thanks to MrWhite, but we're not quite there yet.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**
Fixed the Wordpress redirects by renaming the index file of Wordpress to `index-wp.php` and adapt the rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index-wp.php [L]
```

So effectively I use MrWhite's updated rule to forward access on the front page (index.php), then I filter the few /zzz sub-pages with the rules above, and everything else is then forwarded to either the actual server paths or to Wordpress (index-wp.php) with those last rules.

**--- SOLVED ---**

Comment: Do you have a `DirectoryIndex` document located in the root of `example.com`? eg. `index.html` or `index.php` etc.?

Comment: The index.php of Wordpress is located at the root.

Comment: What version of Apache are you on?

Comment: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Answer (score 1):

> The index.php of Wordpress is located at the root.

mod_dir may be issuing an internal subrequest for the directory index (ie. `index.php`) before mod_rewrite/mod_proxy catches the request, in which case your directive won't match. However, there are other issues with your directive...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^($|\/$|\?|\/\?)
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yy.example.com [P]
> ```

The *substitution* string is missing a trailing slash after the hostname. *Something* needs to append this in order to make a valid HTTP request. In the case of an external redirect, the *browser* effectively appends the trailing slash here.

The *CondPattern* `^($|\/$|\?|\/\?)` is overly complex and matching too much. It will only ever match the 2nd alternation segment (ie. `\/$`) - if any. The `REQUEST_URI` variable *always* starts with a slash and does not contain the query string. There is also no need to backslash escape the slash here (there are no regex delimiters). However, this `RewriteCond` directive is not required - you can perform the necessary check in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - which will also be more efficient.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ https://yy.example.com/ [P]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^(index\.php)?$` matches either `/` or `/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks, but that actually caused a 400 error for me. I may have to point out again that the RewriteCond seem to be fine (even if too complex), because if I use [L,R=301] for the RewriteRule, the url is rewritten correctly (but of course visible to the user, which I do not want). It's just when using [P], nothing seems to happen at all.

Comment: Hhhmm I don't see how this would generate a 400 Bad Request, except if there is an underlying issue with the proxy or perhaps a conflict with other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Please include the contents of you `.htaccess` file in your question, with these directives in-place. Do you have other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: The directive `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^($|\/$|\?|\/\?)` is the same as simply `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$` since scenario 1, 3 and 4 are "impossible" (unless `?` is URL encoded in the URL-path and you are intentionally accepting requests of the form `/%3Ffoobar` - which that condition will accept). This may be "OK" for the redirect (since processing stops and the redirect response is immediately sent back to the client), but we are dealing with mod_proxy which might be triggered later, after mod_dir has processed the request.

Comment: Also try changing the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ from `^(index\.php)?$` to `^index\.php$` - do you still get the 400 response?

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question with the progress, your new pattern does work, but it also conflicts with Wordpress now.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with my .htaccess containing only

```
RewriteRule ^ "/info.php?orig=%{REQUEST_URI}" [P]
```

When I requested http://localhost/, REQUEST_URI contained "/index.html", which of course did not fit with your second RewriteCond.

Comment: Thanks. I may have to point out again that the RewriteCond seem to be fine, because if I use [L,R=301] for the RewriteRule, the url is rewritten correctly (but of course visible to the user, which I do not want). It's just when using [P], nothing seems to happen at all.

Comment: Does your backend understand HTTPS?